# Website of online food ordering

Tags: phrase-usage

Are there any difference between phrases below which were written with “of” and without “of”? Is the first one written with “of “ correct and does it have same meaning?

> 1)The UK-based website of online food ordering Eat-Much has picked up a third round of funding totaling $64 million, its biggest yet, to further build out its online food ordering service.
>
> 2)The UK-based online food ordering website Eat-Much has picked up a third round of funding totaling $64 million, its biggest yet, to further build out its online food ordering service.

Comment: Hello. Could you undelete your [last question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234915/use-of-in-a-state-in-different-way), please? I had written an answer but I could not post it because it was deleted.

Comment: Hello I asked  a new question with better example . I had to deleted because the example is not good enough to meet my expection about the question in my mind.

Comment: I have seen this happen to other users, so this is a warning, deleting posts  [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234916/use-of-in-a-state-in-which) and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234927/use-of-in-a-state-that), **could** lead to a [question ban](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4861/why-i-have-you-have-reached-your-question-limit-if-i-do-not-have-any-question/4862#4862). It is best to listen to experienced users and improve your questions rather than posting variations on the same theme.

Answer (score 1):

The “of” is optional - that is, both sentences are possible grammatically.  The version without “of” sounds much better though.

But both sentences are not natural and easy to read. For example, the “online” concept is effectively repeated by using both “website” and “online” (every website is online). You repeat “online” and “food ordering” at the end of the sentence too, making it all sound a bit awkward. In fact the public interface may be a “website” but is more likely (or additionally) an app-based interface. For this reason what you talking about is most often referred to as a “platform” in English.